# SELinux domain_auto_trans()

Tags: linux, selinux

I am trying to get information on domain_auto_trans() function in SELinux. 
I tried to look in SELinux webpages, but couldn't find a clear definition of the function and its syntax. Can someone please refer me to a page where it gives me an example of this function and its usage.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can find documentation about this macro in the [RHEL4, Red Hat SELinux Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/SELinux_Guide/rhlcommon-section-0023.html). Note that the section about this macro has disappeared in subsequent versions of the guide.

> domain_auto_trans and domain_trans
>
> When you want a particular transition to be the default transition behavior for a domain, use domain_auto_trans, from core_macros.te. It calls domain_trans() to do the actual work. If you just want to allow a transition to take place and handle the context with setexeccon(), you can use just a domain_trans():
>
> ```
> # domain_auto_trans(parent_domain, program_type, child_domain)
>   define(`domain_auto_trans',`
>   domain_trans($1,$2,$3)
>   type_transition $1 $2:process $3;
>  ')
> ```
>
> The domain_trans macro allows the parent process a typical set of permissions to transition to the new domain. It sets a few dontaudit rules, allows the parent process to execute the program, allows the child to reap the new domain and exchange and use file descriptions with the parent process, as well as write back to the old domain via a named pipe (FIFO). Finally, the new domain is given permission to read and execute the program, making the program the entry point for the domain.
>
> Because only one transition can be the default for a given pair of types, you can have one domain_auto_trans rule followed by multiple domain_trans rules that allow other options. These can be used by a security-aware application.